# fabric.js used to draw line. When lines overlaps. I am not able to select particular line

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am using `fabric.js` to build html5 based tool.

I am having issue on selecting a line when two lines are overlapping. Can anyone suggest me how I can select particular line when overlapped?

var lineData  = "M -0.5134763565610655 -7.294808400647957 L 0 2.6920000000000073 L 8.392091599408445 -2.746087769348536 M 0 2.6920000000000073 L 1.375 0 M 1.8884763565610654 9.986808400647964 L 1.375 0 L -7.017091599408445 5.438087769348543";

```
main.line  = new fabric.Path(lineData,
   {
    left    : infoData.left,
    top    : infoData.top,
    width    : infoData.width,
    height    : infoData.height,
    type    : "connector_line",
    main    : main,
    strokeLineCap  : "butt",
    selectable   : false,
    fill    : "transparent",
    stroke    : main.lColor,
    strokeWidth  : main.lWidth,
    strokeDashArray : main.dashArr
   });
```

so I add a line from the path data.
at that time the line will be curved , continous line etc.
at that time the selection area is the rect (minX, minY, maxX, maxY). Overlapping lines causes rect overlap hence unable to select line when two lines are overlapped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you post your code and the results or any errors you are seeing, someone will be more likely able to help you.  You can edit your original question to provide more information.

Comment: can  i select object from just when we selected the line area no rect boundary?